# How to add Style to DevExpress BarButtonItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, devexpress

I have some DevExpress **BarButtonItem** layered on top of one another. So I need to ensure they are of the same width (e.g. if the content is longer or shorter, the buttons would "shift" around in between true and false visibility).

But I could not figure out how to add the width property to **BarButtonItem**. I tried the following but it doesn't work, and there is no Width property for BarButtonItem.

```
<dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="btn1" Content="Foo">
   <dxb:BarButtonItem.Style>
       <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
   </dxb:BarButtonItem.Style>
<dxb:BarButtonItem>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no direct way to specify BarButtonItem width or height, but you can specify the width or height of [BarButtonItem.Content](http://documentation.devexpress.com/Silverlight/DevExpressXpfBarsBarItem_Contenttopic.aspx) via the [BarButtonItem.ContentTemplate](http://documentation.devexpress.com/Silverlight/DevExpressXpfBarsBarItem_ContentTemplatetopic.aspx) property:

```
<dxb:BarManager Name="barManager" CreateStandardLayout="True">
    <dxb:BarManager.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="RedBarButtonItemContentWithFixedWidth">
            <Border Background="Red" Width="100">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </dxb:BarManager.Resources>
    <dxb:BarManager.Items>
        <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="btn1" Content="Foo"
            ContentTemplate="{StaticResource RedBarButtonItemContentWithFixedWidth}"/>
        ...
```

Comment: Any idea why this only works when the ribbon style of the BarItemLink that references btn1 is set to SmallWithText? The following BarItemLink will show the correct tempalate: <dxb:BarItemLink BarItemName="btn1" RibbonStyle="SmallWithText" /> But this won't: <dxb:BarItemLink BarItemName="btn1" RibbonStyle="Large" />